# php xdebug doesn't work - Error: Socket not writable

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, xdebug-3

I use php xdebug, xampp and VScode, but today xdebug unexpectedly stopped working... 
The error it gives me is this: "continueRequest thread ID 1 error: socket not writable".
Can anyone here help me get it working again?
I have another php project that works fine, but in this project it gives me this error. Thanks in advance.

this is my php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.1.5-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.remote_log="C:\xampp\php\tmp\xdebug.log"
```

I've tried in a different port but nothing happens

this is the full error in Debug Console:

```
Error: socket not writable
    at c:\Users\andre\.vscode\extensions\xdebug.php-debug-1.31.1\out\dbgp.js:140:24
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Connection.write (c:\Users\andre\.vscode\extensions\xdebug.php-debug-1.31.1\out\dbgp.js:132:16)
    at Connection._executeCommand (c:\Users\andre\.vscode\extensions\xdebug.php-debug-1.31.1\out\xdebugConnection.js:683:20)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (c:\Users\andre\.vscode\extensions\xdebug.php-debug-1.31.1\out\xdebugConnection.js:625:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at Connection._handleDataChunk (c:\Users\andre\.vscode\extensions\xdebug.php-debug-1.31.1\out\dbgp.js:111:22)
    at Connection._handleDataChunk (c:\Users\andre\.vscode\extensions\xdebug.php-debug-1.31.1\out\dbgp.js:76:26)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\Users\andre\.vscode\extensions\xdebug.php-debug-1.31.1\out\dbgp.js:47:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
```

Comment: The default port for XDEBUG2 was 9000 and in XDEBUG 3 it is 9003, I assume you changed it AND also checked the port number param in VSCode `"php.debug.port":`?

Comment: Or maybe in `launch.json`

Comment: Actually I have 2 different versions in my xampp php folder... So maybe they generate a conflict...

Answer (score 0):

This configs solves my issue:

```
   [Xdebug]
    zend_extension="/path/to/xdebug.so"
    xdebug.mode=debug
    xdebug.start_with_request=yes
    xdebug.client_port=9003
    xdebug.discover_client_host=true
```